# Remain on session information between apps and websites

Tags: google-analytics

I have a very strange question :)

If I have an android app or ios app and the registration occurs through a website (not within the app itself) then once registration completed it goes back to the app.

Here is the full scenario. 
The user goes to the app, click on register and then he will be taken to the website to complete the registration, and finally returns to the app.

In order to remain the same session a usage of client id / user id can be placed on the table. but the question is, how about doing that with different web properties?

Meaning.... the app has the following UA number (UA-123456789-1) and the website has the following UA number (UA-123456789-2)

Is there a way to remain both visits within the same session or at least don't break the session from the app prospective ???

Thanks
Mo

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to have a single session span two separate properties in Google Analytics. If you wanted the entire sign-in flow to be a single session, you'd have to send the hits to the same property.

Note, however, that it's possible to send hits from a website to two different properties, so you could still have your website be a separate property but also send hits to your app property.

Check out the documentation on [creating multiple trackers](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers#working_with_multiple_trackers) to send hits to separate properties: